# Reading all attributes and all child nodes under an xml tag using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employee>
<name id="8011810" loc="CHN"  act="TVN">Ram
<Prev_name pid="789546" ploc="TN"  pact="VRT">Kumar</Prev_name>
</name>
<project ppid="8011475" pploc="HYD"  ppact="BT">ODC</project>
<team tid="456987" loc="BAN"  Act="SCP" size="small">CMS</team>
</employee>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="employee">
    <xsl:for-each select="@*|node()">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output:

```
8011810CHNTVNRam789546TNVRTKumar8011475HYDBTODC456987BANSCPsmallCMS
```

Note: All the subchild nodes, including their attributes, must be read. Subchild node_names may be anything.

End output should be a concat of everything under `<employee>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get really everything under `employee` and nothing more from other tags/text-nodes I chose an approach with a mode-attribute on the templates. The templates with the mode-attribute do only match if they are called with the same mode-attribute in `apply-templates`. I used a `normalize-space()` on the text-nodes to get rid of the line-breaks and spaces.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="employee">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="only" />   <!-- apply identity template to employee children only -->
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()" mode="only">                    <!-- only for employee children -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="only" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" mode="only">                    <!-- text()-nodes only for employee children -->
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />                              <!-- suppress all other text -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, attributes are ignored, so you need a template to copy them. Try this:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @ Max Toro , Hi . Thanks for the help. your approach will work. But it will read the entire document. But i need to read only those under 'employee' tag alone.